# Tool/library to compress/decompress on the fly

Tags: linux, compression

I am looking for library or linux command line tool that allows to compress and decompress on the fly. By 'on the fly' I mean something that will work with following sh script:

```
> while:; do; echo "foobar"; sleep 1; done; | <tool to compress> > file &
> sleep 4
> <tool to decompress> file 
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
```

As far as I understand `gzip` and zlib will not work here. My "test" produces following output:

```
> while:; do; echo "foobar"; sleep 1; done; | gzip > file &
> sleep 4
> zcat file 
gzip: file: unexpected end of file
```

Are there any options?

Comment: `gzip` can easily do it, you just need to tell it to read from `stdin`: `some_command | gzip - > output.gz`

Comment: @Panki you don’t even need that, `gzip` will read from stdin and write to stdout by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gzip` does work, but it only writes 16KiB compressed blocks (in my tests), and since your input compresses *really* well, it takes a while to get there. If you run

```
while :; do echo "foobar"; sleep 1; done | gzip > file &
```

wait a little and then kill only the first part, you’ll get a valid compressed `file`.

If you want to test without killing anything, drop the `sleep`:

```
yes foobar | gzip > file &
```

After a few seconds you’ll see `file` increase to 16KiB.